# Two transistor pair inverter and one transistor pair inverter

Tags: ac, inverter, phase, single-phase

Today I made DIY inverter (the top one) [image]

I managed to achieve ~2 volts from 5V usb, everything seemed to be ok. But I have question - is this the right way to make inverter? I also found the bottom schematic on the internet and I think it would work differently. I drew two graphs the way I imagine it works. Is it right? Does bottom schematic produce better AC current than top one? Because I think the bottom works like any wall AC socket - there is phase and "zero". Which is better? I'm thinking about making a more powerful VFD for single phase motor (a basic ventilator, that connects to wall AC socket). Which schematic should I use?

Comment: What sort of inverter do you mean?

Comment: Your first circuit is ***bridged*** or a ***full-bridge***, because your output forms a bridge between two driven nodes. (Those nodes should be driven oppositely to each other, of course.) Your second circuit is just a ***half-bridge*** output (and you can easily see it uses half the BJTs, too.)

Comment: Your second drawing has a 'typo'; D would not connect to the negative supply, it connects to the center of a dual supply, - a supply that has + and - and center 'ground' or reference (typically a center-tapped transformer and bridge diode, and 2 banks of filter capacitors). The top configuration runs on a single-ended supply, and needs twice the circuitry. [Dual supply is usually preferred if designing for powering from a transformer supply vs the full bridge inverter circuit. Single supply would be used if powering from a single battery source.]